# discord bot automatically sends challenge to each individual channel every 24 hours

Tags: python, discord.py

I am brand new to making discord bots, and I'm wanting to make a bot that sends coding challenges for 5 different languages (python, java, javascript, c#, and html).  I have set the channels up in my test discord, and I've given the bot admin to be able to read and write in channels, etc. I am trying to figure out how to get it to be on a 24 hour timer, and when that timer reaches zero, it sends out the code challenges for each language to it's corresponding discord channel.

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
TOKEN = ''

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx, member: discord.member):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.name}")

@bot.command()
async def 

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

so far I've been able to bring the bot online, and I've learned how to give it custom commands, but I have zero idea on where to start for what I'm trying to do, and any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated :) TYIA

Comment: Check out https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/

Answer (score 0):

You can use discord.ext.tasks for a loop that runs every 24 hours. If you have the guild object you can use `for channel in guild.channels:` and then send the message. You can get the guild object with the id: `bot.get_guild(id)`. All together it would look like this:

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks # Import the tasks module

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
TOKEN = ''

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    challenge.start() # Start the loop

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx, member: discord.member):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.name}")

@tasks.loop(seconds=86400) # Loops every 24h
async def challenge():
    guild = await bot.get_guild(id) # Gets the guild object by the id
    for channel in guild.channels:  # Runs a command in every channel
        await channel.send(message) # Says the message

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

**I did not test this and it may not work.**

Comment: I put in my bot token, and when I ran it, it threw back the following error:

Comment: guild = await bot.get_guild(id)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but you have to put the ID of the Server that you want to send the messages to in bot.get_guild(id). Simply replace the id in the () with the ID of the server.